# Is Chromium HTML5-compliant?

Tags: html, chromium

**Is [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home) HTML5-compliant?**

Before you downvote this due to lack of research, try finding out for yourself! I am *shocked* to discover there seems to be nothing on Google or in the Chromium docs that indicate any level of HTML5 support.

If it *does* support HTML5 features, which ones?

If it *doesn't* support HTML5, are there any open source browsers out there that do?

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: Thanks @Dai - it's an enormous backstory not worthy of the brevity expected at SO.

Comment: If you consider "web platform" here to be "HTML5 + JavaScript", https://www.chromestatus.com/features is as close to a feature list for Chromium as I've found.

Comment: Thanks @hcs (+1) - I can't tell from that page, does "web platform" imply HTML5 [Offline/AppCache](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) as well as [WebStorage/LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)?

Comment: [Web storage](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5345825534246912),  [Appplication cache](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6192449487634432)

Comment: Thanks again @hcs (+1) - so are these features in development, or currently a part of latest Chrome?

Comment: The entry for the feature says what version it was enabled by default in, if it was enabled by default they consider it production-ready in that version. These particular features have both been enabled by default since version 6 (5 for AppCache)

Comment: Thanks again @hcs (+1) - then I think your link adequately explains how Chrome tracks various HTML5 features. If you answer this question with a link annd a brief explanation for future-comers, I'll happily give you the green check. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrated from comments...

The Chromium Project maintains a nice searchable [feature list](https://www.chromestatus.com/features). This details what features they support, what version this support became default in (if any), what other browsers support it, and what applicable standards exist. There is also an indication as to what degree a feature is adopted by developers.